# How do I get an ASP RadioButtonList where the buttons don't have any text next to them?

Tags: asp.net

I have a list of radio buttons on my ASP.NET page displayed thus:-

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="my_radio_box"
                     runat="server"
                     AutoPostBack="True"
                     RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                     onselectedindexchanged="my_function">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

but I would like the buttons to be displayed without any accompanying text (there'll be other things on the page to make clear what is required). I've tried leaving no space in between the >< in the list item, and also a space and a non-breaking space, but the value text is displayed whenever I do this.

How do I have a radiobutton with no text?

(I've tried setting the foreground colour the same as the background colour; this works, but doesn't seem right to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.text.aspx) says "*If the Text property contains Nothing, the get accessor returns the value of the Value property. If the Value property, in turn, contains Nothing, String.Empty is returned.*"

So I imagine you could use a whitespace character in the `Text` property to 'fool' it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a whitespace to the `Text` property of the `ListItem`?:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text=" " />
```

**EDIT**

I created a test case using the above, and it works:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rd" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; the first suggestion is what I adopted; the second is one I tried that didn't work.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Is there a reason why you accepted the other answer if you used my solution? Was there something in that answer that I didn't address in mine?

Comment: The other answer also includes your suggestion; while I appreciate your help, I can only accept one. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'm just a bit surprised, since I posted my answer first. You got it working though, so I guess that's all that matters.